# Pass a parent to a function in MAUI. Binding issues

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, binding, maui

I am trying to solve binding issues in .NET MAUI.

As you can see in screenshot 1, I have student card information. The first field is a label, then they go to three entries. The idea is when a user clicks the button, these 3 entries should be readable and the edit button should be replaced to a submit button.

[Screenshot 1 - Student Card Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqMv6.png)

In this case, I need to pass a parent (stacklayout) to my EditButton event function.

The slice of the XAML page looks like:

```
<Grid  ColumnDefinitions="3*,1*" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource cardbg}" RowSpacing="3">
       <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="StudentStack" 
                                                 Margin="20">                                                                                          
         
        <Label x:Name ="idlab" Text="{Binding StudentId, StringFormat='Id={0:D0}'}" TextColor="   {StaticResource cardtextbg}"/>
        <Entry Text="{Binding StudentName}" TextColor="{StaticResource cardtextbg}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
         <Entry Text="{Binding StudentSurname}" TextColor="{StaticResource cardtextbg}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
         <Entry Text="{Binding StudentGPA}" TextColor="{StaticResource cardtextbg}"
                                               IsReadOnly="True"
                                               Margin="10"/>
         </StackLayout>

         
         <ImageButton x:Name="edit"   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"                                                
Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodels:StudentsViewModel}}, Path=EditStudents}"
CommandParameter="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type models:Student}}}"                                                 
HeightRequest="{Binding Height, Source={x:Reference idlab}}"                                               
Source="edit.svg"  
BackgroundColor="CornflowerBlue">                                                                                            
         </ImageButton>
</Grid>
```

So, the card is a grid with 2 columns and 1 row, there is a stacklayout inside of it, and ImageButton on the right side of the card.

I tired the following code to bind my ImageView for passing parent.

XAML:

```
Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodels:StudentsViewModel}}, Path=EditStudents}"
CommandParameter="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type models:Student}}}"
```

StudentsViewModel:

```
public ICommand EditStudents { get; set; }

 public StudentsViewModel()
 {
   EditStudents = new Command(onEditStudents);
 }
private void onEditStudents(object obj)
{
   var b = 3 + 4;
}
```

The object represents the Student model, but it is not an object of the StackLayout, therefore I don't have access to turn on/off entries of the specific card when the EditButton was clicked.

That's my issue.

Again, how I can bind my XAML page to ViewModel, and pass StackLayout(the parent of the specific card), due to turning on/off the readable properties of 3 entries?

How the function must should like?

Comment: your VM should not directly modify the View.  You should bind the elements of the view to properties of the VM, and then modify those properties and allow the binding to update the View for you.

Comment: @Jason, I know, but how I can identify which card (memory address) was fired? Anyway, I need to pass an object that can identify this. How?

Comment: just bind `StudentID` to the `CommandParameter`.  Or pass the entire `StudentModel`

Comment: So, I changed my XAM Page to this 

```Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodels:StudentsViewModel}}, Path=EditStudents}"
CommandParameter="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodels:StudentsViewModel}}}"```

And I am having my ViewModel now, but how I can access the specific StackLayout/Grid in what is the cell it's pressed? So, yes I have a parameter of type ViewModel, is it useful?

Comment: Does StudentsViewModel contain a list of students?

Answer (score 0):

Like the comment below your question already mentioned.

Bind your CommandParameter to your actual StudentModel amd change then the Properties which will have an influence about the visual behaviour

Comment: Any code guidence?

Comment: what do you want to do with the parent StackLayout ? I need a little bit more info for thast

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings?view=net-maui-7.0

And most importantly, focusing on this part:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings?view=net-maui-7.0#bind-to-an-ancestor

I see that you have:

```
{Binding StudentName}
```

and it is working...

The way you bind the student should be:

```
{Binding .}
```